# How to add a custom JSP tag in the Eclipse IDE is Customize Palette?

Tags: eclipse, jsp, jsp-tags, code-snippets

I am using Eclipse IDE which contains JSP plugin. I want to add a custom JSP tag.

In my snippets panel I did a right-click > *Customize*:

[image: JSP Tags]

A *Customize Palette* dialog opens with a button to import files:

[image: Customize Palette]

What kind of file I need to put and what is the contents of this file?

Comment: Here are some examples: https://wiki.base22.com/display/btg/Snippets+for+Eclipse You can also create new items and export them, e. g. to share them with others.

Comment: ty, i'll try that.